# Mockito Mock not returning a value

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Hi all I'm trying to test a feature that creates a timestamp but I can't get my mocked time stamp creator to return the value I want. Instead it returns null as if I never told the mock what to do. This is my mock:

```
        Mockito.when(mockTime.getYear()).thenReturn(YEAR);
        Mockito.when(mockTime.getMonth()).thenReturn(MONTH);
        Mockito.when(mockTime.getDay()).thenReturn(DAY);
        Mockito.when(mockTime.getHour()).thenReturn(HOUR);
        Mockito.when(mockTime.getMinute()).thenReturn(MINUTE);
        Mockito.when(mockTime.getSecond()).thenReturn(SECOND);
        Mockito.when(mockTime.getEonAndYear()).thenReturn(mockEon);

        dataTypeFactory = Mockito.mock(DatatypeFactory.class);
        Mockito.when(dataTypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Mockito.any(GregorianCalendar.class))).thenReturn(mockTime);
```

And here is the actual function using the mocked datatypeFactory:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedTime = ZonedDateTime.now(UTC_ZONE_ID);
        GregorianCalendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.from(zonedTime);
        this.time = dataTypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
```

Any ideas why this.time = dataTypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar); is returning null when dataTypeFactory is the mocked dataTypeFactory created above?

This test **WAS** working fine when I was passing in a new GregorianCalendar into the datatypefactory but now that I need to format with the proper timezone it all fails

Comment: The purpose of mocking is to mock the behavior, not the data. You should create and return an actual instance of `mockTime`.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I don't think that's my issue here

Comment: can you add your full test? I don't see where `mockTime` is initialized. Stacktrace would be also helpful, maybe there is some additional exception thrown